# Plot derivations of multiple logistical curves with ggplot and purrr

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr, derivative

The rows of data frame "pars" hold the two parameters defining logistical curves:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)

pars <- data.frame(
  diff = c(-1.5, 2.5),
  disc = c(1.2, 2.5)
)
```

These two curves can be plotted with map() and ggplot() like this.

```
icc <- function(x) map(
  1:nrow(pars),
  ~ stat_function(fun = function(x)
    (exp(pars$disc[.x]*(x - pars$diff[.x])))/(1 + exp(pars$disc[.x]*(x - pars$diff[.x]))))
)
ggplot(data.frame(x = -5 : 5)) +
  aes(x) +
  icc()
```

[image]

The corresponding derivations can be plotted like this:

```
disc1 <- 1.2
disc2 <- 2.5
diff1 <- -1.5
diff2 <- 2.5

icc1 <- function(x) (exp(disc1*(x - diff1)))/(1 + exp(disc1*(x - diff1)))
icc2 <- function(x) (exp(disc2*(x - diff2)))/(1 + exp(disc2*(x - diff2)))

info1 <- Deriv(icc1, "x")
info2 <- Deriv(icc2, "x")

ggplot(data.frame(x = -5 : 5)) +
  aes(x) +
  stat_function(fun = info1) +
  stat_function(fun = info2)
```

[image]

However, I'd like to use a more generic approach with preferably purrr() for the derivations as well since I'll need a function for a varying number of curves. Maybe there's a solution with pmap() that could iterate through a data frame with parameters and apply function and derivation to each row. Unfortunately, I was unlucky so far. I am extremely grateful for any helpful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option may look like so:

1. I have put the parameters for your curves in a data.frame
2. Making use of a function factory and `pmap` to loop over the params df to create a list of your `icc` functions.

The rest is pretty straighforward.

3. Loop over the list of functions to get the derivatives.
4. Use map to add the `stat_function` layers.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(Deriv)
#> Warning: package 'Deriv' was built under R version 4.1.2
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(
  disc = c(1.2, 2.5),
  diff = c(-1.5, 2.5)
)

icc <- function(disc, diff) {
  function(x) (exp(disc*(x - diff)))/(1 + exp(disc*(x - diff)))
}

icc_list <- pmap(df, function(disc, diff) icc(disc, diff))
info_list <- map(icc_list, Deriv, "x")

ggplot(data.frame(x = -5 : 5)) +
  aes(x) +
  map(info_list, ~ stat_function(fun = .x))
```

[image]

**EDIT** Incorporating different colors or ... is not a big deal, e.g. you could use `purrr::map2` to loop over both `info_list` and your vector of colors to assign a color to each of your functions or derivatives:

```r
colorVec <- c("red", "blue")

ggplot(data.frame(x = -5 : 5)) +
  aes(x) +
  map2(info_list, colorVec, ~ stat_function(fun = .x, color = .y))
```

[image]

**EDIT 2** Finally, we could apply the same idea to get a legend like so, where instead of setting the `color` as an argument we map on the `color` aes and set the colors via `scale_color_manual`:

```
colorVec <- c("red", "blue")
labelsVec <- c("f1", "f2")
names(colorVec) <- labelsVec

ggplot(data.frame(x = -5 : 5)) +
  aes(x) +
  map2(info_list, labelsVec, ~ stat_function(fun = .x, aes(color = .y))) +
  scale_color_manual(values = colorVec)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Stefan for that very good answer that opens a lot of new possibilities. Unfortunately, I'm now struggling coloring the functions. Before, I've added a hex-color vector (length corresponds to nrow(pars)) inside the map function like this:

~stat_function(fun = function (x) (exp(pars$disc[.x]*(x - pars$diff[.x])))/(1 + exp(pars$disc[.x]*(x - pars$diff[.x]))), color = colorVector[.x])

Is there a way to add such a coloring when map is getting the functions from a list?

Comment: Hi @MaVe. Sure is this possible. See my edit showing one approach to add colors using map2. And in case you want to set other params like e.g. linetype you could switch to `pmap`.

Comment: I could have tried for a long time with map(). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a way to add legend for the color of line? I tried aes(color = .y), but the color is misaligned.

Comment: @yuw444. Sure. Basically you were right by mapping on the `color` aes. See my second edit for an approach to get a legend.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it in a very similar way to the icc plotting:

```
deriv_icc <- function(x) map(
  1:nrow(pars),
  ~ stat_function(fun = function(x){
    exb <- exp(pars$disc[.x]*(x-pars$diff[.x]))
    pars$disc[.x]*(exb/(1+exb) - exb^2/(1+exb)^2)
    }))

ggplot(data.frame(x = -5 : 5)) +
  aes(x) +
  deriv_icc()
```

[image]

This simply recognizes the fact that the derivative of the logistic CDF for this problem is the discrimination parameter times the logistic PDF:

[image]